# implement search operation using firestore sub collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an ecommerce app with 4-5 different categories(mobile products, bedsheets, doormats, computers etc.) and want to show them under their own categories like these [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xYXB.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FPOv.jpg) [imag3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ1va.jpg) [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj5Nn.jpg) and also want to implement "search products by name" functionality in my app .I know how to make sub-collections but Can anyone tell me how to structure firestore data base so that I can fetch data under their own individual categories and using the same data how to implement search product by their names. I am new to flutter please explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

The best fit I can see for your solution would be to use [Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Just make sure the subcollection have the same name and you could query over them.

Comment: Thank you for your expensive reply. what about search operation

Comment: How do you mean `search`? If you want to make `full text search` you would need to use a third party service like elastic search or algolia.

Comment: can you please explain elastic search or algolia in a bit detail . Thank you

Comment: I would recommend this links. They explain it better than a single comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search , https://tony-mogoa.medium.com/how-i-implemented-full-text-search-on-firebase-ae1c6370157e 
 , https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search

Comment: It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted. Thx